# Pip is not installing packages on docker

Tags: python, django, docker, pip, docker-compose

So i have a docker image created with [django cookiecutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) and i need to install additional python packages for my app to work. The package im trying to install is [django markdown](https://github.com/klen/django_markdown), so i edited the base.txt in the requirements folder, and when i run the command `sudo docker-compose -f dev.yml run django pip install -r requirements/base.txt`
 it shows me this output:
[image]

So it looks like it actually installed the package but if i run it again it looks like its the first time and tries to install it again, also if i try to run my django project i get `ImportError: No module named 'django_markdown'`. What could be causing this issue and what is the workaround i should do?.

I've tried installing different packages even with the `sudo docker-compose -f dev.yml run django pip install [package name]`
command with the same results

Comment: It you use `docker run` a second time you will spawn a new container without the changes of the first. Run the installation from `Dockerfile` while building you image.

Comment: You should create a virtual environment of your python project, copy that folder to the docker container or mount bind the folder and then run the app directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebuild your image When you try to install new package in docker